# Did Sanhedrin use Oral law along with Written Law

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, oral-torah, sanhedrin

Did Sanhedrin use Oral law along with Written Law in their decisions?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The Talmud in Tractate Sanhedrin talks about what sort of mistakes a judge on the Sanhedrin might make, and explicitly distinguishes between those obvious from an explicit Written Law verse vs. something in the Oral Law.